# AJAX запрос не возвращает ничего

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, ajax

```
function ajax_login_init(){

    wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'redirecturl' => home_url(),
        'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
    ));
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
}

if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
}


function ajax_login(){


    $info = array(
    'user_pass' => $_POST['password'],
    'user_login' => $_POST['username'],
    'display_name' => $_POST['username'],
    'first_name' => 'Nazar',
    'last_name' => 'Koniaka',
    'role' => get_option('default_role') ,
    'user_secondry_email' => 'test@tst.com'
);
    // $info['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    // $info['password'] = $_POST['password'];
    // $info['login'] =
    // $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        $new_user_name = $_POST['username'];
        $new_user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $new_user_password = $_POST['password'];
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $new_user_email );
        $userId = $user->ID;
        $user_data = array(
            'user_email' => $new_user_email,
            'user_pass' => $new_user_password,
            'role' => 'subscriber'
            );
        $user_id = wp_insert_user($user_data);
            if (!is_wp_error($user_id)) {
            echo 'we have Created an account for you.';
            $credentials = array(
              'user_login' => $new_user_email,
              'user_password' => $new_user_password,
            );
            wp_signon( $credentials );
            $userS = get_user_by( 'email', $new_user_email );
            $userIDs = $userS->ID;
            echo $userIDs;
            } else {
              if (isset($user_id->errors['empty_user_login'])) {
                $notice_key = 'User Name and Email are mandatory';
                wp_signon($user_data);
                echo $userId;
                
                } elseif (isset($user_id->errors['existing_user_login'])) {
                  $credentials = array(
                      'user_login' => $new_user_email,
                      'user_password' => $new_user_password,
                    );
                    wp_signon( $credentials );
                    echo 'jopa';
                } else {
                echo'Error Occured please fill up the sign up form carefully.';
                }
            }
    } else {
        echo 'to vibav';
    }

    die();
}
```

Код JS

```
$('.form__blue-button').on('click', function(e){
        let ajaxscript = {
            ajax_url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajaxscript.ajax_url,
            data: { 
                action: 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                username: 'Mevzu11',
                user_email: 'asd3ddcz@gmail.com',
                new_user_email: 'qwasdasd123',
                password: 'Aa1357aa'  },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
    })
```

За то что в запросе нету nonce просьба не предъявлять))) позже добавлю)

возвращает это:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (e)
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
complete: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
error: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
readyState: 4
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "parsererror"
success: ƒ ()
then: ƒ (t,n,r)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

@Simon, заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в строке `dataType: 'json'` в ajax запросе, закоментил и всё работает, всем спасибо)))